# Information on Western digital hard drive serial number

Tags: hard-drive, serial-number

What type of information can I get from checking the serial number of a WD hard drive using the Linux command `sudo lshw -class disk`?

Comment: The serial number. What did you expect? You need to provide some context.

Comment: Have you tried running the command and seeing what output you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo hdparm -i /dev/sda`

is probably hat you are looking for.  I am not 100% it works for WD drives, but it worked for my Toshiba